# Получить сумму значений ключей словаря

Tags: python, dict

Имеем словарь:

```
{'Агутин': [('4',), ('4',), ('6',), ('2',), ('1',)], 'Путин': [('4',), ('1',), ('4',), ('1',), ('0',)], 'Пушкин': [('3',), ('0',), ('3',), ('3',), ('0',)]}
```

Требуется получить сумму значений ключей(например "Агутин": 4+4+6+2+1 = 13, и т.д)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = {'Агутин': [('4',), ('4',), ('6',), ('2',), ('1',)], 'Путин': [('4',), ('1',), ('4',), ('1',), ('0',)], 'Пушкин': [('3',), ('0',), ('3',), ('3',), ('0',)]}

res = {key: sum(map(lambda i: int(i[0]), value)) for key, value in data.items()}

print(res)
```

ну или чуть покороче:

```
res = {key: sum(map(lambda i: int(i[0]), data[key])) for key in data}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def sum_(dict_, key):
    return sum(map(lambda el:int(el[0]), dict_[key]))
```